# about concat in pandas : using row data to create new columns

Tags: python, pandas

The same question has been posted on pydata google group.

I want to do a custom concat i.e using the rows in a group by object
to create new cols.

Here is an contrived example:

```
Input data frame
name age
foo     12
bar     14

df = pandas.DataFrame({  'name':['foo','bar'],'age': [12,14] })



expected output, a pandas data frame with four cols 
foo 12 bar 14
```

PS: I am looking for an efficient solution as this would be applied to
a grouped pandas object containing 800k odd groupings.

Sample 800k data would have following structure. I am still using an analogy as actual data is scientific and column names might not be intuitive

```
Subject (grouped by col)
          Name     Age        mark1   
          Foo      12         80     
          Bar      14         90
```

What we want from this grouped by data is the following data frame

```
Subject Foo 12 80 Bar 14 90
```

Comment: Could you give more details on how the 800k df looks like?

Comment: Sure @elyase..details are present now

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want a DataFrame `Subject Foo 12 80 Bar 14 90`? (how is one line a DataFrame?)

Comment: see also same question on google group pydata: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pydata/8sWqBRwRXNU

Answer (score 0):

You want to reshape the values of the DataFrame so:

```
In [43]: pandas.DataFrame(df[['name', 'age']].values.reshape(1, 4))
Out[43]:
     0   1    2   3
0  foo  12  bar  14
```

This should be efficient as reshape() returns a view. Credits [@Wouter Overmeire](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pydata/8sWqBRwRXNU).